# Is there a way to start an activity without showing it?

Tags: android

I currently have 2 activities in my project, activity A (MAIN) and activity B.

Activity B does some parsing using Jsoup so it takes a bit of time to load everything.
So I'm wondering if it's possible to start Activity B as well on the app launch but not show it?

Comment: why not getting all stuff in Activity A, after everything done then start activity B

Answer (score 1):

**Why you can't Use Async task when you load Activity A, at that time In background Through Async task start parsing data so you get all data.**

```
private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> { 
protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {
//Use Your parameter instead of this
// code that will run in the background 
return ;
}

protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
// receive progress updates from doInBackground
}

protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
// update the UI after background processes completes
 }
}
```

**Executions of AsyncTask class from main thread:**

```
new DownloadFilesTask().execute(url1, url2, url3);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not set setContentView() for activity B .

Comment: What if I want to access activity B later?

Comment: You can call onResume() method when you get back to it again.

Answer (score 0):

Long running background task should be done on service or Async.
But if there is specific need to start invisible activity you have all info below...

Remember on **Headless** activity you can not do long running task, this is just to trigger something

```
public class HeadLessActivity extends Activity {
private static final String TAG = "HeadLessActivity";
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.d(TAG, "on create called");
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Log.d(TAG, "on on resume called called");
    moveTaskToBack(true);
    try {
        Log.d(TAG, "sleeping for 3 seconds");
        Thread.sleep(3000);//todo:small work here
        Log.d(TAG, "resuming");
        Log.d(TAG, "finishing");
        finish();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.d(TAG, "could not sleep: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

add activity in Manifest

```
<activity android:name=".HeadLessActivity" android:theme="@style/HeadLessTheme.NoDisplay"/>
```

add theme

```
<style name="HeadLessTheme.NoDisplay">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowDisablePreview">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoDisplay">true</item>
</style>
```